# array_udiff for multi-dimensional array is not working

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I am trying to remove duplicate entries/items from a multi-dimensional array what is matched in another array.

Here is my code I am using (I have take/provide only the necessary code to reproduce the error)

```
<?PHP
$strInfoData = unserialize(file_get_contents('./1.txt'));
$strRecomData = unserialize(file_get_contents('./2.txt'));
$strArrayDiff = array_udiff($strInfoData, $strRecomData, 'fMultiDimensionArrayDiff');
echo count($strInfoData) . ' = ' . count($strRecomData) . ' = ' .  count($strArrayDiff) . '<br>';
exit();

function fMultiDimensionArrayDiff($a, $b)
{
    if(trim($a['OnlineId']) === trim($b['OnlineId']))
    {
        return 0;
    }
    else
    {
        return -1;
    }
}
?>
```

When executed it returns:
838 = 749 = 833

So, above means `array1`($strInfodata) has 838 item. `array2` ($strRecommData) has 749 items. But unfortunately arrayDiff has 833 items where it should be 838-749 = 89 right?

here is the text files:

[1.txt](https://www.dropbox.com/s/dc5laamkxs74t2k/1.txt?dl=0)

[2.txt](https://www.dropbox.com/s/2hqbgvhqx3y5o0j/2.txt?dl=0)

Password for the both text file is: abcd1234

So, where is the problem in my code?

any help would be highly appreciated :)

Comment: your array contain only one key value ?? means 'OnlineId' only one key exit in $a and $b ?

Comment: @ParthChavda, thanks for your reply, nope sir, my first (main) array have 8 key value and 2nd array (only to used for find duplicate) is yes, only have one key value.. thanks again...

Comment: can you give me a password of 1.txt and 2.txt so i will test your code

Comment: @ParthChavda, i am sorry but may you didn't notice? password is already there. however again it is: "abcd1234" (without quotation mark). thanks...

Comment: For me, when trying to read `1.txt` I'm getting `unserialize(): Error at offset 617 of 265136 bytes`

Comment: @RamRaider, thanks and sorry for late reply, sir, i have changed the text file link, earlier it was uploaded to a text sharing site and seems that's the problem, now i uploaded to dropbox.. would you please check now? :)

Comment: There is some sort of problem with the data, getting a similar error but on a different line now.

Comment: @RamRaider, sir, is there any other way i can share the text files? should i zip it first?